# A conditional macro that distinguishes the alphabet from the others

Tags: conditionals, greek

I am trying to make a macro in the form `\eqrel{}{}{}` such that it gives `#1 \quad #2 \quad #3` if `#2` is either an English or Greek letter, and `#1 #2 #3` otherwise.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqrel}[3]{
    \ifcat#2\relax
    {#1#2#3}
    \else
    {#1\quad#2\quad#3}
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$ \eqrel{x}{\sim}{y} $\\
$ \eqrel{x}{R}{y} $\\
$ \eqrel{x}{\Omega}{y} $

\end{document}
```

But this does not detect Greek letters:

[image]

Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Should also the slanted forms (like `\varOmega`) be considered? It would be of course possible but I believe it would be much easier to define e.g. a starred form of the macro to use the "spaced" version.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to define `\newcommand{\eqrel}[3]{#1\mathrel{#2}#3}`?

Comment: @egreg You're right... That's the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: @Hermis14 I added also a way to enlarge the space for symbols that are not relations.

Comment: @egreg I used `\quad` to exaggerate the difference. `\mathrel` is good enough but thank you for the elaborated answer.

Comment: Next time it may be better to explain what you actually want to do (proper spacing of relation symbol R) instead of how you think would solve the problem — or alternatively you may want to [edit] the title to reflect what you want better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be doable; in case `#1` is a control sequence, you may assume it's a `\mathchardef` token; then you could check the relative mathcode to see the math group it's taken from.

However, there is a simpler way around:

```
\newcommand{\eqrel}[3]{#1\mathrel{#2}#3}
```

so the middle symbol is treated as a relation symbol, independent of its standard nature.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqrel}[3]{#1\mathrel{#2}#3}

\begin{document}

$ \eqrel{x}{\sim}{y} $

$ \eqrel{x}{R}{y} $

$ \eqrel{x}{\Omega}{y} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use more space around a nonrelation symbol, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\check@rel}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{\thickmuskip=0mu${}#1{}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{${}#1{}$}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@=\wd\tw@
    % #1 is not a relation symbol
    \mathrel{\;#1\;}%
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\eqrel}[3]{#1\check@rel{#2}#3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ \eqrel{x}{\sim}{y} $

$ \eqrel{x}{R}{y} $

$ \eqrel{x}{\Omega}{y} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Experiment with the additional space to suit your taste.